# AWS ElasticSearch does not accept certain CloudTrail documents

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

**Update2**

I was pointed to this project. I will implement it as I like the solution.

https://github.com/chariotsolutions/aws-examples/tree/trunk/cloudtrail_to_elasticsearch

---

**Original question:**

Certain type of AWS CloudTrail events does not get to AWS ElasticSearch. Finally, I narrowed down to a very simplified JSON document that fails, and at this point, I could use some insights.

So despite that, I do POST some-random-index-every-time/_doc

```
POST ddd/_doc
```

```json
{
  "eventVersion": "1.05",
  "eventTime": "2020-10-21T00:37:26Z",
  "eventSource": "s3.amazonaws.com",
  "eventName": "PutBucketPolicy",
  "awsRegion": "eu-central-1",
  "errorCode": "AccessDenied",
  "errorMessage": "Access Denied",
  "requestParameters": {
    "bucketPolicy": {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "logs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "logs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
              "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:root"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
              "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:root"
            ]
          },
          "Action": "s3:PutObject",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::whatever/*"
        },
        {
          "Sid": "ProtectLogs",
          "Effect": "Deny",
          "Principal": "*"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the same error all the time:

```json
{
  "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
  "reason": "mapper [requestParameters.bucketPolicy.Statement.Principal] of different type, current_type [text], merged_type [ObjectMapper]"
}
```

If I remove this block from JSON - document gets accepted:

```json
{
  "Sid": "ProtectLogs",
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Principal": "*"
}
```

**Update1**:

I *think* I should create a template and define a mapping for this field so ES doesn't get mixed up

Comment: *Elasticsearch Ninja* has given you the answer, but I'll add to it by saying that there a _lot_ of CloudTrail events that will fail using a simple PUT. [Here](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/aws-examples/tree/trunk/cloudtrail_to_elasticsearch#event-transformation) is a description of how I solved the problem (and the Lambda that I use to upload events to ES).

Comment: @kdgregory that is actually the ultimate answer to my question which I didn't ask, but it is my end goal :) I already have lambda which processes all kinds of logs - but in the case of CloudTrail I was simply putting JSON what I got.

Comment: @kdgregory need to adjust topic - so other people can find it.. I know I am not the only one struggling with CloudTrail. I think you should put an answer too - Hopefully, Elasticsearch Ninja will understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is happening due to `Principal` field which is present at the same level but in your first block its of type `object` like below

```
   {
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "logs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"
          }
        },
```

And in last block, which when you removed it worked, it is of type `text`, which creates the issue and error message is also very clear and complaining about incompatible merge types, `text` to `object` type.

**Instead of removing the block, you can try renaming the field to `Principal_new` and it will work, otherwise create a static mapping/template for all your index fields so that these fields are not mixed up, which you already guessed**