# how can i create elasticsearch index with multi type field?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
 "settings": {
  "index": {
   "mapping": {
    "ignore_malformed": "true",
    "include_type_name": "true"
   }
  }
 },
  "mappings": {
   "properties": {
    "address": {
     "type": "text",
     "field": {
      "type": {
       "type": "keyword"
      },
      "ip": {
       "type": "ip"
      },
      "comment": {
       "analyzer": "whitespace",
       "type": "text"
      }
     }
    }
   }
 }
```

Error:
**`elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', "failed to parse field [address] of type [text] in document with id 'UA7RSHUBK7u8_ZjU0JQR'`******

This is my code and Error message.
How Can I Fix this mapping json?
What do you think is causing it?
Thanks for your response.

Comment: could u pls look at prev. comment

Answer (score 0):

> The [include_type_name parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/removal-of-types.html) in the index creation, index template,
> and mapping APIs will default to false. Setting the parameter at all
> will result in a deprecation warning from Elasticsearch 7.x

**The `fields` setting is allowed to have different settings for fields of the same name in the same index.**

Modified index mapping will be :

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "mapping": {                   <-- note this
        "ignore_malformed": "true"
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "address": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {          <-- note this
          "type": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "ip": {
            "type": "ip"
          },
          "comment": {
            "analyzer": "whitespace",
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Refer to this Elasticsearch official documentation on [fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#multi-fields) to know more about this.**

Adding a working example with index data, index mapping(same as given above), search query, and search result.

Index data:

```
{
  "address":"Khajrana circle"
}
{
  "address":"indore"
}
{
  "address":"192.168.1.1"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "indore",
      "fields": [
        "address",
        "address.type",
        "address.comment"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64455730",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0925692,
        "_ignored": [
          "address.ip"
        ],
        "_source": {
          "address": "indore"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I write [field -> fields] but this is error, too.

Comment: @riajang which elasticsearch version you are using? I tried my index mapping in ES version 7.8, and it is working fine.

Comment: @riajang please use the same index mapping, as given in my answer. I have removed 1 parameter from index settings also

Comment: @riajang did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Answer (score 0):

`mapper_parsing_exception` exception is caused when Elasticsearch is not able to **parse the document properly according to its mapping** due to various reasons, for ex: if in your mapping, you define a field of type `object` and try to store `text` field, a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64455425/aws-elasticsearch-does-not-accept-certain-cloudtrail-s3putbucketpolicy-document) is asked where I explained it in more detail.

As mentioned in your error message, your document id `UA7RSHUBK7u8_ZjU0JQR` has an improper format for your `address` field, you need to provide the document JSON for this id in your question and complete error message to further debug the issue.